# NTILE function error in Navicat MySQL

Tags: mysql, navicat

I am trying to using the NTILE function to create deciles in a dataset using Navicat for MySQL. My query is:

```
select NTILE(10) over (order by 'amount') decile, *
from dataframe d
order by 'amount';
```

I get the error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by.....
```

Can anyone help figure out what is wrong with my query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySql didn't implement `NTILE` yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTILE is what is called a window function ([MS SQL Info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)).

MySQL does not have window functions: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions

Comment: How would you do something like select 3 quartile of a set in mysql?